# Como imprimir só a primeira pagina

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde, tenho esse código na minha planilha.

```
Sub Imprimir()
    Dim LocalPDF As String
    'DEFINIR O LOCAL ONDE SERÁ SALVO O ARQUIVO
    LocalPDF = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("H5") & " - " & Range("C7")
    'GERAR O ARQUIVO PDF
    Planilha10.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=LocalPDF & ".pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    'LIMPAR OS REGISTROS
    Range("B14:E19").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

A planilha tem mais paginas, como faço pra salvar so a primeira pagina?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, Lucas.

Adicione a linha `From:=1, To:=1`, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ChDir "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pasta1.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        From:=1, To:=1, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```